# Can we specify directory path with the property file while using ResourceBundle class in Java?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I want to place my properties files in some folder, but I am not able to read them because we can specify only the bundle name in static `getBundle()` method on *ResourceBundle* object.

Suppose bundle is: *myFile.properties*
Current path is: *src*
I want to keep my properties file in: *src/temp*

So when I am using:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("temp/myfile", currentLocale);
```

it is throwing an exception "can't find bundle". I want some way to specify the path. Please suggest me some way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("temp.myfile", currentLocale);
```

The `baseName` supplied in the `ResourceBundle.getBundle` call is supposed to be a fully qualified class name. So it has to be written separated with dots. Also note that this makes `temp` a package in your java code (which I don't think is a good idea). It is better to put the properties file in a proper package like `com.xyz.abc`. Then you can access it using

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.xyz.abc.myfile", currentLocale);
```

Comment: though i am putting "myFile.properties" into a pefect package, its still found missing @ run.
I put it as you suggest : 

"com.xyz.myFile"

Did this works for you

Comment: Do i need to mention something in property file by commenting or using annotations?

Comment: I got the file name mixed up. With the correct file name it should work.

Comment: I have a file "tagValue.properties", copied in "src" and "src/temp" directory but when i am using :- bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("tagValue"); it works but when i am using :- bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("temp.tagValue"); it throws "java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name temp.tagValue"

Comment: @ abhin4v. You are correct, i was having problem with the path.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you are using the wrong filename (myfile != myFile).

For a file `myFile.properties` in a directory `temp` on the classpath, this code should work:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("temp.myFile");
```

Comment: I have a file "tagValue.properties", copied in a "src" and "src/temp" directory but when i am using :-

bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("tagValue");

it works

but when i am using :-

bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("temp.tagValue");

it throws 

"java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name temp.tagValue"

Comment: @Kuri - check your classpath. I expect that using your ClassLoader's `getResource("/temp/tagValue.properties");` method will also fail (return null). It is not possible to diagnose the problem without more information about your runtime environment (classpath arguments, class binary locations, etc).

Comment: Yeah Mr.McDowell you are right, its giving me null for("temp/tagValue.properties") but when i am using it with ("tagValue.properties"), its giving me absolute path for the file.
okey now i got the problem.
Thanks a lot.