# Properties file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to run the below sample code in java.

```
import java.util.Locale;  
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class InternationalizationDemo {  

  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);  
    System.out.println("Message in "+Locale.CANADA_FRENCH +":"+bundle.getString("greeting"));
  }
}
```

1.The above code executes properly when `MessageBundle.properties` is placed in the class path.
But I want to execute the above code successfully by removing the `MessageBundle.properties` from the classpath and placing it in some other location.
How can I do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598240/can-we-specify-directory-path-with-the-property-file-while-using-resourcebundle

Comment: No I don't want to place the properties file in any of the packages.

Comment: I want it in any of the drives like c:\ or D:\ drive

Comment: @vinayaka So then just check answers. There are already two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load properties file externally by this:

```
// Path to your file, if you have it on local, use something like C:\\MyFolder or \home\usr\etc
File file = new File("YOUR_PATH");
URL[] url = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, new URLClassLoader(url));
```

Example is from here: https://coderanch.com/t/432762/java/java/absolute-path-bundle-file

You are able to use remote Properties file or file which is saved on local.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PropertyResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) and get the path of your properties file from a `System` property for example something like that:

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("config.path");
ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new FileReader(configPath));
```

Then in your launch command you will need to add `-Dconfig.path=/path/to/my/config.properties`