# What would be a good way to display static message in facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I came across following from a managed bean and .xhtml in jsf 2.x application. This static variable has a long string value and is referred by the bean in .xhtml page to display the message. Armed with limited experience of Java/JSF, I decided to improve it somehow.

1. Take out static as a first step
2. Create proper getter/setter methods
3. Load the text message from properties file.
4. Bind loaded value to the message variable

Not too convinced of myself so I googled it from here and found this thread: [fetching the values from a property file inside a XHTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121760/fetching-the-values-from-a-property-file-inside-a-xhtml-file). That sounds promising but hoping to find the best practice in regards to load/referring static message in JSF.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Foo {
    private static String message = "....long...message...";

    // getter only available
    public String getMessage() { .... }
```

From .xhtml page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{foo.message}" />
```

Comment: Depends on the contents of the message. UI labels, error messages are usually contained in a `.properties` file and fetched from it. This ensures code maintainability and quick turn around. In case the above static message is not going to be reused anywhere else and is kind of unique to the application, you may retain it in the managed bean, however I would suggest to go with the `.properties` file option as you never know when more things get added in the application.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply back with a good suggestion. Yes, it turns out to be verbose error message. I will go with .properties path. It is also good to know if it is unique to the application, it is ok to retain the managed bean.